# Only enforce module docstrings?

Tags: python, pylint

I'd like to gradually add documentation to my project. My first idea was to run `pylint projectname --disable=all --enable=missing-docstring`, but it turns out it enforces all kinds of docstrings, not just module docstrings. Is there a way to adjust that?

Comment: What is stopping you from gradually adding documentation and using the pylint warnings as a guideline, not an error?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi having CI automatically enforce this lets you have a measure of progress as well as a clean way of telling whether a Git branch conforms to guidelines. It works in my organisation (to a degree).

Answer (score 0):

`pip install flake8_docstrings`

At the moment of writing this question, it appears that [pylint doesn't yet have that](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1164). It's possible to add this this kind of enforcement by installing `flake8_docstrings` `flake8` module, which introduces a lot of fine grained warnings, for example:

```
D100 Missing docstring in public module
D101 Missing docstring in public class
D102 Missing docstring in public method
D103 Missing docstring in public function
D104 Missing docstring in public package
D105 Missing docstring in magic method
D107 Missing docstring in __init__
D205 1 blank line required between summary line and description
D209 Multi-line docstring closing quotes should be on a separate line
D400 First line should end with a period
D401 First line should be in imperative mood
```